# Splash screen is resizing incorrectly

Tags: android, splash-screen, xamarin

I am using the style below to show a splash screen in my Xamarin Android application however the image always shows with incorrect sizing. I would like it to resize with the correct dimensions however it always expands to fit the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreenimage</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerCrop</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

The splash screen activity

```
  [Activity(MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", NoHistory = true)]
  public class SplashScreenActivity : Activity
  {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
      base.OnCreate(bundle);

      // Start our real activity
      StartActivity(typeof(LoginActivity));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One issue is that windowBackground is sized to full screen size, inclding status bar at top or bottom of device. But the status bar is still shown. My response to [Android Activity Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17517570/420175) uses windowContentOverlay, which excludes the status bar.

Answer (score 9):

For background drawable you should use layer-list. For example make bitmap_splash.xml:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/background"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splashscreenimage" />
</item>
```

and then use it in your style:

```
...
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bitmap_splash</item>
...
```

Comment: I want to give the bitmap width however it is not supported under api 23. Is there anyway to make the logo bigger for all devices? thanks

Answer (score -3):

When I had trouble displaying images correctly in my app I found this helpfull site: [Android scale types](http://etcodehome.blogspot.nl/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html)

It shows the outcome of the different types of scale that you can use. Hope this helps!

Comment: `ScaleType` works only for `ImageView`, but the question is about `windowBackground`.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at:

[Android: Scale a Drawable or background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400782/android-scale-a-drawable-or-background-image/9362168#9362168)

Basically, this allows you to specify how to clip or stretch an image when the image is smaller than the view bounds of the screen. I think the author of this answer gives a good explanation, and it might be what you're looking for.